# Calling the constructor from the assignment operator

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I am overloading the assignment operator for a class Arr. This is implemented by using the destructor to delete the old object (and release allocated memory), and then use the copy-constructor (which is previously overloaded) to make the calling object a copy of rhs. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0omT.png)  picture shows two different ways to do this (only line 50 and 57 differ). Why do the second solution work, but not the first?

The error message is "type name is not allowed"

```
Arr& Arr::operator=(const Arr& rhs) {
    this->~Arr();
    this->Arr(rhs); // I get an error here: type name is not allowed
    return (*this);
}


Arr& Arr::operator=(const Arr& rhs) {
    this->~Arr();
    this->Arr::Arr(rhs);
    return (*this);
}
```

I know it is possible to use copy-and-swap, but still: what goes wrong here?

Comment: This code is not exception safe and if you know about swap, why would you ever ask such question? Why would you write such bad code! The problem with your code is that it is illegal to call the constructor explicitly. The only way to call the constructor on already allocated memory, is to use placement new (at least with C++ 03). If second syntax works on your compiler, then I doubt it is standard.

Comment: *"Why do the second solution work, but not the first?"* - Probably because you are using a defective compiler or invoke it with the wrong set of options.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, in GCC both are not allowed. My guess is that if your compiler allows one but not the other, then it is to avoid disambiguation.

When you write `this->Arr()`, the compiler cannot know that you meant to call the constructor, rather than just instantiate a new object.

When you write `this->Arr::Arr()`, then the compiler knows that you call the *static* function `Arr()` of the class `Arr`.